# Can a stack trace exception be added to SLF4J LOGGER?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, stack-trace

Here's SSCCE adding SLF4J LOGGER messages and throwing a null pointer exception. It uses a list appender to examine the log:

```
package my.tester;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.read.ListAppender;

public class TestException {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Logger LOGGER = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("TestException");

        final ListAppender<ILoggingEvent> listAppender = new ListAppender<>();
        listAppender.start();
        LOGGER.addAppender(listAppender);

        NullPointerException testException =  new NullPointerException("Oops!");

        LOGGER.info("doing stuff");
        LOGGER.error("problem here", testException);

        Assertions.assertTrue(listAppender.list.get(1).getFormattedMessage().contains("Oops"));

    }
}
```

There are only 2 lines in the log appender:

```
doing stuff
problem here
```

so naturally, the test to check for the exception fails with the following output:

```
16:45:15.577 [main] INFO TestException - doing stuff
16:45:15.591 [main] ERROR TestException - problem here
java.lang.NullPointerException: Oops!
    at my.texter.TestException.main(TestException.java:34)

Exception in thread "main" org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <true> but was: <false>
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertTrue.assertTrue(AssertTrue.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertTrue.assertTrue(AssertTrue.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue(Assertions.java:162)
    at my.texter.TestException.main(TestException.java:39)
```

How can the stack trace from the null exception be added to the log?

Comment: LOGGER.error("problem here", testException);

this will print stack trace from exception, since your class has only 1 call, you see only one line in Stack Trace.

Comment: Thanks, but not relevant to my question

Answer (score -1):

Try by changing

LOGGER.error("problem here", testException);

to

LOGGER.error("problem here", testException,testException);

Comment: Adding testException once or indeed as many times as you like, adds nothing extra when the appender is examined. The above is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so can be easily tested for anyone interested.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).